# use variable instead of table name

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

First Thanks for your comments. The array for Names if the tables names like, Name1, Name2, Name3,.. but we have different names.

However, May I need to explain by other way to be understand.

What I want to do is compare old DataBase with new DataBase (Both in MS Access). Each has many tables (>20), and each table has many fields like “Number”, “ Name”, etc, and put the differences in “Output” Table.

Then to make code short as possible, I want to use Loop and use Variable refer to Tables names. I put all Tables Names in below table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ0Ut.jpg)

***TablesNames***
Old_DB_Tables_Names   |   New_DB_Tables_Names

Items_List            |   Items_List

Items_Price          |    Items_Price
Items_Specs          |    Items_Specs
Items_Size           |    Items_Size
Items_Warehouse      |    Items_Warehouse
Items_Spare          |    Items_Spare
Items_Quantity       |    Items_Quantity
:
:   :
:

```
Dim TablesNames As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_List As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Price As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Specs  As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Size As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Wearhouse As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Spare As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Quantity  As ADODB.Recordset
:
:
Dim I as Integer 
I=0

Table1=TablesNames.item("Old_DB_Tables_Names").value
Table2=TablesNames.item("New_DB_Tables_Names").value

While TablesNames .EOF=False 
   if Table1.fields(I) <> Table2.fields(I) then

Output.Fields.Item("Number").Value Table2.Fields.Item("Number ").Value
Output.Fields.Item("Name").Value Table2.Fields.Item("Name ").Value
:
:
End If
I=I+1

Wend
```

The issue VBA not accept statement `[Table1.fields(I) <> Table2.fields(I)]`.

Is it: we can’t refer to a table by its name, and to any of its fields and get a value from a record in that field?
If you have anther way, Please let me know.

Comment: Compare fields? Names of these or values (which record(s))??

Comment: Compare the values in those tables. but the point statement " =Table.fields(0) " not accepted since "Table" in variable name not real table name. What is the correct statement?

Comment: Do you want to compare  Table.fields(0).Name  or Table.fields(0).Type  or  Table.fields(0).Value  or any of a dozen parts of a field?  To get at these parts we need to Open  Names1  and keep it open,  and then for each OTHER table like Names4 we need to also Open it..   If we are stepping thru just the columns we can open the Schema, but if we are stepping thru the rows we might need to compare the Keys in Names1  vs Keys in Names 4...  In other words we need more info, and maybe some sample rows from one of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with the first part:

```
Dim TablesNames As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_List As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Price As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Specs  As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Size As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Wearhouse As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Spare As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Items_Quantity  As ADODB.Recordset
```

What it looks like you are trying to do from the rest of your code:

Bring all the information from each table into your code.

What you are actually doing:

Creating empty recordset variables, to store table data and then never storing any table data.  i.e. TableNames, Items_List, etc. are all variables, and they currently have nothing to do with anything, at all, they are completely empty and have no meaning to the rest of your code in their current states.

Next we have:

```
Table1=TablesNames.item("Old_DB_Tables_Names").value
Table2=TablesNames.item("New_DB_Tables_Names").value
```

What it looks like you are trying to do from the rest of your code:

Store instances of your tables using the name of the table.

What you are actually doing:

Accessing the value of a field in the recordset TableNames and storing that value in a variable named Table1.  From the name, I assume you are expecting this to be a TableDef, but you are using it as either a string or a value type, but I can't tell because I'm not seeing where you declared it.  If you didn't declare it, you need to type "Option Explicit", without the quotes, at the top of every single one of your modules, right now, seriously, stop reading and go do that.

```
While TablesNames .EOF=False
```

If you had set the recordset of TableNames in your code, this will work, as long as you don't have a space before .EOF

```
if Table1.fields(I) <> Table2.fields(I) then
```

What it looks like you are trying to do from the rest of your code:

Access a field from the TableDef stored in the variable Table1.

What you are actually doing:

Nothing, since, from your code, Table1 is either a string or value type and there is no method nor property named "fields" for any string or value types, you aren't doing anything.

Finally we have

```
Output.Fields.Item("Number").Value Table2.Field`enter code here`s.Item("Number ").Value
Output.Fields.Item("Name").Value Table2.Fields.Item("Name ").Value
```

What?

All of this leads me to believe that you haven't grasped the syntactical structure of VBA.  While many of us here would like to help you, in most cases, we aren't going to be able to just give you an answer that will work completely, with out some sort of modification by you.

Comment: I can't add long test Comments, then I edit my Question. Please look for it.